# Parallel execution in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to threading concept in python. Find the below script

```
def func1(con_no, con_name, *argv):
"This functions takes around 3-4 min to completes"

def func2(con_no, con_name, *argv):
"This functions takes around 5 min to completes"

def runthread(*fns):

   proc = []
   for fn in fns:
       p = Process(target=fn)
       p.start()
       proc.append(p)
   for p in proc:
       p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':

runthread(func1(con_no, con_name), func2(con_no, con_name))
```

The above code waits for func1() to completes its operation and goes to func2().How to start both the functions parallely, so that func2() do not wait for func1() to complete its operation. Please note I am using python 2.7 version.

> **Updated the question**

Comment: Your problem is here: `runthread(func1(), func2())` ... because you included the parens, you called the functions and then passed their results to `runthread`. Do `runthread(func1, func2)` instead.

Comment: @tdelaney I have a parameters to pass to both functions

Comment: @louis make your example realistic to your issue. If you have to pass parameters show functions that take parameters and also show where you intend to pass those parameters..

Comment: @PaulRooney I have edited the question!

Answer (score 2):

You started func1 before runthread is called:

You should write:

```
runthread(func1, func2)
```

To pass parameters, read these examples: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

Comment: I have a parameters to pass to both functions.

Comment: @louis: Then pass them. Your example doesn't include that, you need to figure out how to organize the params that go with each function call.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have `con_no` and `con_name` initialised with some values, you can use `partial`:

```
from functools import partial

...

runthread(partial(func1, con_no, con_name), partial(func2, con_no, con_name))
```

Comment: Good! The `partial` builds a function from original one (first parameter) and passes the following parameters to the it when called. So you can pass the original function and the parameters you want without calling it, delegating the calling to the `Process` instance.